# Change label colors of a custom UIButton with multiple labels

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uilabel, subclass

I am creating a custom button with multiple labels.  I want to be able to change the text color of the labels on highlight/normal UIControlStates.  I know its possible to change the title text color based on control states, but I can't seem to figure it out for custom labels within the button.  Any ideas?

Comment: The code I used with @Rich's help is below in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kinda complicated, but I have a book that talks about this it's called Advanced iOS 4 development. basically you have to use the runtime to swap out the setHighlighted method.

Edit: it's technically for tableviewcells but its in [this](http://code.google.com/p/iphone4/downloads/detail?name=Chapter9.tar.gz&can=2&q=) under table view whiten

Comment: note that it will need to be changed a little because UIButtons have different instance variable and methods. to do it easily give a tag to the custom labels and in setHighlighted: call turn all to white on the views with that tag.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the idea @Rich.  I subclassed UIButton and put this code in the new class.

Heres the code I used:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)bHighlighted
{
    [super setHighlighted:bHighlighted];

    if (bHighlighted) {
        [label1 setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [label2 setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }else {
        [label1 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [label2 setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally subclassing uibutton is a real pain cuz it's a class cluster. if you nslog a button after init'ing it, it will say something like UIRoundedRectButton so if you subclass it you will have to implement a bunch of it's methods. it might be easier to dynamically subclass it by copying the custom style button (ie. [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];) class the code for this is here: http://davedelong.com/blog/2010/10/07/fun-objective-c-dynamic-subclassing

Comment: Yeah it worked.  I am only using the button for a custom type, so in the init function I call [MyCustomButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

Comment: another idea, you could forward all messages in your subclass to the UICustomButton class except for setHighlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use some of the inherited [UIControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl) methods (such as sendAction:to:forEvent:) This offers even finer control than with UIButton.